# starmac-ros-pkg and simulated_quadrotor

Tags: ros, quadcopter, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
I want to work with tha package [simulated_quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulated_quadrotor) from the [starmac_robots](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac_robots) stack. So, i installed [starmac-ros-package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac-ros-pkg) following the tutorial.

The problem is that there isn't the simulated_quadrotor stack in my folder, i missed this package.
Why there is the documentation about it, but there isn't it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12078/starmac-ros-pkg-and-simulated_quadrotor/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i solved the problem thanks from [here](https://bitbucket.org/bouffard/starmac-ros-pkg/changeset/c0accc574817).

Now, can you help me to simulate? what should i do?

---

Originally posted by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) with karma: 155 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0